# Excel function I wrote is displaying #value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to calculate the life time value of a customer. The customer's value churns (decreases by a percentage each year). I need to NPV the customer value after it has been churned over the whole period. I.e for period one I churn that value over the entire period and then add it to an array. Then excel moves onto the next value in the cell adjacent and does the same thing but the period has become smaller by 1 period. Once the array has been populated I NPV these values.

The reason I tried to write this function is that I require this calculation to be done in one cell. I am aware I could accomplish this in a seperate sheet. However each value churned over the period would require its own row. When I have 100+ it starts to get excessive.

I wrote the function below in order to try calculate this. I am fairly certain my understanding of the problem is correct, yet my VBA skills are lacking. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Option Explicit
Function NPVLTV(discount As Double, n As Double, Value As Double, Churn() As Range) As Double

    Dim ValuesChurned() As Range
    ReDim ValuesChurned(n - 1) As Range

    Dim k as Double
    k = Value
    For i = 0 To n - 1
        ValuesChurned(i) = k
        k = Value * (1 - Churn(i)) ^ i 
    Next i

    NPVLTV = NPV(discount, ValuesChurned())

End Function
```

I expect to get one value of the Net present value of the cell churned over the entire period. I am however getting the #VALUE error. I have been using this input as a test for the function

```
=NPVLTV(0.025, count(N67:$BO$67) ,336 , N67:$BO$67)
```

The Range is simply an array of 0.01.

Comment: You've declared an array `ValuesChurned` but then you haven't sized it so you will get an error as soon as you try and populate it.

Comment: Hey Rory, thanks for the feedback. I have changed it to Dim ValuesChurned(n - 1) As Double. However I am still getting the error. Regards

Comment: You can't declare an array using a variable for the size. Use `Redim` instead of `Dim`

Comment: Don't post code in comments. Edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Sorry I have updated my question

Comment: Minor comment:  You have not `Dim`ed `k`, or defined the type.  Add `Option Explicit` at the top of your code (or turn it on in the Options Menu), and VBA will complain if you try to use a Variable that has not been declared

Comment: Thanks I have updated my question with your suggestions.